# Logging events / actions in Node.js backend for later analysis

Tags: javascript, node.js, backend

I've almost completed a web application. 
Now we want to log certain events /actions all over the backend application so we can later view and analyze them in a dashboard.

There are likely a million solutions for that but is there one which can be easily integrated with an open source dashboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a JSON logger. Those loggers will enable you to parse the results later on (or in real time) in order to draw graphs (performance, number of events...) or represent what it is going on.

Personally, I would use pino: https://github.com/mcollina/pino as it is very active development wise as well as one of the fastest loggers in Node.js (I am a contributor, please ask if you need any help).

As you can see, in the `README.MD` in the section of `CLI`, there are few examples on how to pipe the output to processes. You could easily write a process that uploads the significant events to your dashboard and manipulate the data as you wish.

Comment: pino + pino-elasticsearch + kibana looks awesome!

Comment: Influx DB seems a pretty cool place for performance series as well as other metrics... I have to explore it.